# Failure of opening Shared Object files

Tags: python, ubuntu, shared-libraries, ctypes

I'm trying to run the python file `tryit.py` which imports another file `uwing.py` which itself imports ctypes and runs a `process_image.c` file. However, when I run it via `$ python3 tryit.py` it gives the error :

> File "tryit.py", line 1, in 
>      from uwimg import *
>     File "/home/siddharth/comp-vision/vision-hw0-master/uwimg.py", line >20, in 
>     lib = CDLL(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), "libuwimg.so"), >RTLD_GLOBAL)
>    File "/home/siddharth/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/**init**.py", >line 356, in **init**
>      self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
>
> **OSError: /home/siddharth/comp-vision/vision-hw0-master/libuwimg.so: >cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

I tired this article from 'itsfoss' - https://itsfoss.com/solve-open-shared-object-file-quick-tip/. but the problem still persists.

this is what I import in uwimg.py file

```
import sys, os
from ctypes import *
import math
import random
```

this is what I import in tryit.py file

```
from uwimg import *
```

Either the shared object files cannot be opened or I'm doing something wrong in running the `tryit.py` file. For homework I'm modifying the `process_image.c` file and checking the rsult by running the `tryit.py` file. Am I doing anything wrong by running the tryit.py file or is the problem in object file sharing ?

Comment: Your code explicitly forms the (qualified) filename to load—and the message says it doesn’t exist.  Does it?

Comment: yes, now that you mention it. It does appear to create a file, but fails to do so.

Comment: */home/siddharth/comp-vision/vision-hw0-master/libuwimg.so* seems not to be found.